# (Some) buttons not working in initially hidden div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress block using react (in the frontend).
The block will initially fetch a list from a server, then display the list using `map`.
For each item, it will render a header, like so:
[image]
As you can see, you can click a header and the content shows up. This content is build in the same `map` and they have their `max-height` and `opacity` set to `0` to hide them. I'm using those properties instead of just `display: none`, because I can CSS-transition them and it looks smoother. I had to blur the content, but you get the idea.

[image]

However, in **some** of the content-divs, the buttons are not working. The links-stlyed-as-buttons (the music services on the left) do not behave as links, although they have their `href` set in the markup. The hover effects do not work either, the cursor does not become the pointy finger and they are not clickable.
A div styled as a play-button has the same issues: in eventListeners I can see the `onClick` being listened for, but the button is not clickable, has no hover, etc.

One noteable thing is: it's not all list entries behaving this way. And if one list entry with broken buttons is open, and you open another content section with *working* buttons, the broken buttons will magically start working. If you then close the content section with working buttons, the formerly broken ones are broken again.

Honestly, this feels like my code is haunted.

Please note: because the length and content of the list is not entirely known, I have to use generated IDs and generated `getElementByID`-queries to interact with the items and can't define states for them (at least I couldn't think of a way to dynamically create states).

React:

```js
    //...
    //releases is useState([]) of an object with metadata of songs
    //comes from a database query, so the columns are known
    {releases.map(release => {return(
      <div key={release.catalogue_index} style={{marginTop: "8px"}}>
        {/*This is the "header", shown in the screenshot*/}
        <div className="layout-row" style={{backgroundColor: "#111", padding: "8px", marginTop: "4px", position: "relative"}} onClick={(event) => {
          document.getElementById(`${release.catalogue_index}-content`).classList.toggle('open');
          }}>
          <div stlye={{flexGrow: 1}} className="layout-stack">
            {/* here the title and some information is displayed*/}
          </div>
        </div>
    
        {/*The content you can show (second screenshot)*/}
        <div className="release-content" id={`${release.catalogue_index}-content`}>
          {/*layout-stack and layout-row are just flex containers with different directions*/}
          <div className="layout-row">
            <img loading="lazy" alt={`${release.title} cover`} src={/*cover.jpg*/}
              className="release-cover" />
            <div className="layout-stack">
              <div>{/*some metadata*/}</div>
              <hr />
              {release.short_description}
              <div style={{height: "16px"}} />
              <div className="layout-row">
                {/*those are the link buttons sometimes not working*/}
                {/*the whole thing only gets displayed if any link got fetched from the database*/}
                {(release.link_bandcamp || release.link_youtube || release.link_spotify || release.link_apple) ? 
                <div className="layout-row">
                  <p className="link-caret"><strong>&gt;</strong></p>
                  <ul className="is-content-justification-center is-layout-flex wp-container-9 wp-block-social-links has-icon-color has-icon-background-color featured-social-group" style={{margin: 0}}>
                    {release.link_bandcamp ?
                      <li style={{color: "#fff", backgroundColor: "#888"}} className="wp-social-link wp-social-link-bandcamp wp-block-social-link wp-custom-social">
                        <a target="_blank" href={release.link_bandcamp} className="wp-block-social-link-anchor" rel="noopener"><img className="svgbutton" src={/*some-logo.svg*/} />
                        <span className="wp-block-social-link-label screen-reader-text">Bandcamp</span></a></li>
                    : null}
                    {release.link_youtube ?
                      <li style={{color: "#fff", backgroundColor: "#888"}} className="wp-social-link wp-social-link-youtube wp-block-social-link wp-custom-social">
                        <a target="_blank" href={release.link_youtube} className="wp-block-social-link-anchor" rel="noopener"><img className="svgbutton" src={/*some-logo.svg*/} />
                        <span className="wp-block-social-link-label screen-reader-text">Youtube</span></a></li>
                    : null}
                    {release.link_spotify ?
                      <li style={{color: "#fff", backgroundColor: "#888"}} className="wp-social-link wp-social-link-spotify wp-block-social-link wp-custom-social">
                        <a target="_blank" href={release.link_spotify} className="wp-block-social-link-anchor" rel="noopener"><img className="svgbutton" src={/*some-logo.svg*/} />
                        <span className="wp-block-social-link-label screen-reader-text">Spotify</span></a></li>
                    : null}
                    {release.link_apple ?
                      <li style={{color: "#fff", backgroundColor: "#888"}} className="wp-social-link wp-social-link-chain wp-block-social-link wp-custom-social">
                        <a target="_blank" href={release.link_apple} className="wp-block-social-link-anchor" rel="noopener"><img className="svgbutton" src={/*some-logo.svg*/} />
                        <span className="wp-block-social-link-label screen-reader-text">Apple Music</span></a></li>
                    : null}
                  </ul>
                </div> : null}
                <audio id={`audio-${release.catalogue_index}`} preload="none"
                  onEnded={() => {document.getElementById(`audio-seek-${release.catalogue_index}`).value = 0}}
                  onLoadedMetadata={() => document.getElementById(`audio-seek-${release.catalogue_index}`).max = document.getElementById(`audio-${release.catalogue_index}`).duration}
                  onTimeUpdate={() => document.getElementById(`audio-seek-${release.catalogue_index}`).value = Math.floor(document.getElementById(`audio-${release.catalogue_index}`).currentTime)}>
                  <source src={/*REDACTED*/} type="audio/mpeg" />
                  Your browser does not support audio.
                </audio>
                <div className="layout-row" style={{alignItems: "center"}}>
                  {/*this is the play button sometimes acting up*/}
                  <div className="play-pause wp-block-button"
                    onClick={() => {togglePlayPause(release.catalogue_index)}}>
                    <img id={`audio-button-${release.catalogue_index}`} className="play-pause svgbutton wp-block-button__link wp-element-button" src={/*play-svg*/} />
                  </div>
                  <input type="range" id={`audio-seek-${release.catalogue_index}`} className="audio-seek" max={100} value={0} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={{height: "16px"}} />
          <div className="layout-stack">
            {/*some flavor text*/}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )})}
```

CSS:

```css
//...
.release-content {
    max-height: 0vh;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.release-content.open {
    opacity: 1;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 16px;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.svgbutton {
  color: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
div.play-pause {
    margin-left: 36px !important;
    height: 38px;
}
img.play-pause {
  box-sizing: unset !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
//...
```

The only thing I could think of was that maybe the wordpress-classes ("wp-...") would somehow break ... but that doesn't make much sense, as some of the the list entries work fine while others don't - all using those same classes.

Comment: You should not be using `document.getElement...` in React instead use [refs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs). For this problem I would suggest a `state` to keep track of the open / close state

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I think I could create a state with an array of booleans for handling open state of the content fields, but that does seem like waste. Every content div would be depending on that array and thus all would re-render every time one should open. Also, how could that affect buttons not working like this?

Comment: You can move this piece of code into its own component which can handle the state internally, open/close audio values. This can also help you with the `document.getElement..`

Comment: You mean a new Component for every list entry and then building the list to be basically just `[<ListEntry entry={objectFromDB} />]`?

Comment: You're mapping over the `releases` so instead of all those elements you can return `<ReleaseComponent release={release} />`

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. Even if it doesn't help, it's the better way to do this. That's what you get for letting it grow organically... However, I'm quite certain, this won't fix the issue with buttons, it just feels like a browser problem. I'll report back once I'm home and done with the refactoring.

Comment: Thank you, @RubenSmn , for making me realize how terribly designed all this was. That's what you get for not planning properly. I have answered the question myself, as the problem went away by using `useState` to show and hide the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on RubenSmn's comment, I had to realize that I did not plan my code well and built terrible anti-patterns.
I have refactored the code to not map into all that markup, but a separate `<Release />` component, which in turn contains the markup.

```js
{releases.map(release => {return(
  <ReleaseComponent key={release.catalogue_index} release={release} />
)})}
```

The new component was then built to not use `classList.toggle`, but proper React states to show and hide the content panels. Also the `document.getElementByID`-queries are gone and replaced by proper React refs.

```js
const ReleaseComponent = (props) => {
  const contentDiv = useRef(null);
  const audioElement = useRef(null);
  const audioButton = useRef(null);
  const audioSeek = useRef(null);

  const [contentOpen, setContentOpen] = useState(false);
  //...
  return(
    //...
    <div className="release-content" ref={contentDiv} hidden={!contentOpen}>

  //...
```

Turns out, if you do things right, they actually work... This was a pretty humbling experience. Thank you, @RubenSmn .